# Modify some attributs in a json files

Tags: json, bash, ubuntu

i have this json schema:

```
{
  "Stock": {
    "Vehicule": [
      {
        "CodePvo": "...",
        "SocieteNom": "...",
        "SocieteAdresse": "...",
        "SocieteCodePostal": "...",
        "SocieteVille": "...",
        "ContactsNoms": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones2": "...",
        "ContactsEmails": "...",
        "IdentifiantVehicule": "10784615",
        "ReferenceVehicule": "1078",
        "NumeroPolice": "1232",
        "StatutStock": "ST",
        "Annee": "2007",
        "Date1Mec": "23-10-2007",
        "GenreLibelle": "Voitures",
        "Marque": "KIA",
        "Famille": "CEE'D SW",
        "Version": "1.6 CRDI115 FAP ISG ACTIVE",
        "Modele": "CEE'D SW 1.6 CRDI115 FAP ISG ACTIVE",
        "EnergieLibelle": "Diesel",
        "PuissanceFiscale": "6",
        "PuissanceReelle": "115",
        "Cylindree": "1582",
        "NbPlaces": "5",
        "NbPortes": "5",
        "Kilometrage": "146013",
        "KmGaranti": "Non garanti",
        "Couleur": "GRIS",
        "BoiteLibelle": "Manuelle",
        "NbRapports": "6",
        "PrixVenteTTC": "4990",
        "PremiereMain": "FAUX",
        "GarantieLibelle": "3 MOIS OU 5000 KM",
        "CategorieLibelle": "Break",
        "EquipementsSerieEtOption": "Peinture métal|Jack et Lecteur Audio Nomade|Prises USB|ABS|Airbags frontaux|Airbags latéraux avant|Airbags rideaux|Allumage des phares automatique|Arrêt et redémarrage auto. du moteur|Banquette 60/40|Clim automatique bi-zones|Filtre à particules|Fixations Isofix aux places arrières|Kit mains-libres Bluetooth|Ordinateur de bord|Pack Sérénité|Phares antibrouillard|Prise iPod|Prises USB, Jack et Lecteur Audio Nomade|Radar de recul|Radio CD MP3|Régulateur de vitesse|Répartiteur électronique de freinage|Roue de secours galette|Sièges cond et pass réglables en hauteur|Verrouillage auto. des portes en roulant|Verrouillage centralisé à distance|Verrouillage centralisé des portes|Vitres arrière électriques|Vitres avant électriques|Volant cuir|Volant réglable en profondeur et hauteur",
        "Photos": "10784615_01_hd.jpg|10784615_02_hd.jpg|10784615_03_hd.jpg|10784615_04_hd.jpg|10784615_05_hd.jpg|10784615_06_hd.jpg|10784615_07_hd.jpg|10784615_08_hd.jpg|10784615_09_hd.jpg",
        "Co2": "119",
        "Poids": "0",
        "PTAC": "0",
        "PTRA": "0",
        "ChargeUtile": "0",
        "Longueur": "4490",
        "Largeur": "1790",
        "Empattement": "0",
        "Hauteur": "1490",
        "Volume": "0"
      },
      {
        "CodePvo": "...",
        "SocieteNom": "...",
        "SocieteAdresse": "...",
        "SocieteCodePostal": "...",
        "SocieteVille": "...",
        "ContactsNoms": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones2": "...",
        "ContactsEmails": "...",
        "IdentifiantVehicule": "11454615",
        "ReferenceVehicule": "1145",
        "NumeroPolice": "1290",
        "StatutStock": "ST",
        "Annee": "2010",
        "Date1Mec": "17-06-2010",
        "GenreLibelle": "Voitures",
        "Marque": "OPEL",
        "Famille": "ASTRA",
        "Version": "1.7 CDTI125 FAP COSMO",
        "Modele": "ASTRA 1.7 CDTI125 FAP COSMO",
        "EnergieLibelle": "Diesel",
        "PuissanceFiscale": "7",
        "PuissanceReelle": "125",
        "Cylindree": "1686",
        "NbPlaces": "5",
        "NbPortes": "5",
        "Kilometrage": "97667",
        "KmGaranti": "Non garanti",
        "Couleur": "MAUVE",
        "BoiteLibelle": "Manuelle",
        "NbRapports": "6",
        "PrixVenteTTC": "9990",
        "PremiereMain": "FAUX",
        "GarantieLibelle": "3 MOIS OU 5000 KM",
        "CategorieLibelle": "Berline",
        "EquipementsSerieEtOption": "ABS|Aide au démarrage en côte|Aide au freinage d'urgence|Airbags frontaux|Airbags latéraux avant|Airbags rideaux|Allumage des phares automatique|Antipatinage|Banquette 1/3-2/3|Capteur de Pluie|Clim automatique bi-zones|Commandes du système audio au volant|ESP|Filtre à particules|Fixations Isofix aux places arrières|Frein stationnement électrique|Kit anti-crevaison|Ordinateur de bord|Phares antibrouillard|Porte-gobelets avant|Radio CD MP3|Régulateur de vitesse|Répartiteur électronique de freinage|Retroviseur intérieur electrochrome|Rétroviseurs électriques dégivrants|Siège conducteur réglable en hauteur|Système audio CD400|Verrouillage centralisé à distance|Verrouillage centralisé des portes|Vitres arrière électriques|Vitres avant électriques|Volant cuir|Volant réglable en profondeur et hauteur",
        "Photos": "11454615_01_hd.jpg|11454615_02_hd.jpg|11454615_03_hd.jpg|11454615_04_hd.jpg|11454615_05_hd.jpg|11454615_06_hd.jpg",
        "Co2": "119",
        "Poids": "0",
        "PTAC": "0",
        "PTRA": "0",
        "ChargeUtile": "0",
        "Longueur": "4419",
        "Largeur": "1814",
        "Empattement": "0",
        "Hauteur": "1510",
        "Volume": "0"
      },
      {
        "CodePvo": "...",
        "SocieteNom": "...",
        "SocieteAdresse": "...",
        "SocieteCodePostal": "...",
        "SocieteVille": "...",
        "ContactsNoms": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones2": "...",
        "ContactsEmails": "...",
        "IdentifiantVehicule": "11824615",
        "ReferenceVehicule": "1182",
        "NumeroPolice": "1323",
        "StatutStock": "ST",
        "Annee": "2011",
        "Date1Mec": "08-03-2011",
        "GenreLibelle": "Voitures",
        "Marque": "PEUGEOT",
        "Famille": "EXPERT FG",
        "Version": "227 L1H1 HDI90 CONFORT",
        "Modele": "EXPERT FG 227 L1H1 HDI90 CONFORT",
        "EnergieLibelle": "Diesel",
        "PuissanceFiscale": "5",
        "PuissanceReelle": "90",
        "Cylindree": "1560",
        "NbPlaces": "3",
        "NbPortes": "3",
        "Kilometrage": "125000",
        "KmGaranti": "Non garanti",
        "Couleur": "BLANC",
        "BoiteLibelle": "Manuelle",
        "NbRapports": "5",
        "PrixVenteTTC": "7490",
        "PremiereMain": "FAUX",
        "GarantieLibelle": "3 MOIS OU 5000 KM",
        "CategorieLibelle": "GRAND UTILITAIRE",
        "EquipementsSerieEtOption": "ABS|Airbag conducteur|Direction assistée|Verrouillage auto. des portes en roulant|Verrouillage centralisé des portes|Vitres avant électriques",
        "Photos": "11824615_01_hd.jpg|11824615_02_hd.jpg|11824615_03_hd.jpg|11824615_04_hd.jpg|11824615_05_hd.jpg|11824615_06_hd.jpg|11824615_07_hd.jpg",
        "Co2": "0",
        "Poids": "0",
        "PTAC": "0",
        "PTRA": "0",
        "ChargeUtile": "0",
        "Longueur": "4805",
        "Largeur": "1895",
        "Empattement": "0",
        "Hauteur": "1942",
        "Volume": "0"
      },
      {
        "CodePvo": "...",
        "SocieteNom": "...",
        "SocieteAdresse": "...",
        "SocieteCodePostal": "...",
        "SocieteVille": "...",
        "ContactsNoms": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones2": "...",
        "ContactsEmails": "...",
        "IdentifiantVehicule": "11844615",
        "ReferenceVehicule": "1184",
        "NumeroPolice": "1325",
        "StatutStock": "ST",
        "Annee": "2006",
        "Date1Mec": "19-01-2006",
        "GenreLibelle": "Voitures",
        "Marque": "PEUGEOT",
        "Famille": "607",
        "Version": "2.7 V6 HDI SIGNATURE",
        "Modele": "607 2.7 V6 HDI SIGNATURE",
        "EnergieLibelle": "Diesel",
        "PuissanceFiscale": "13",
        "PuissanceReelle": "204",
        "Cylindree": "2721",
        "NbPlaces": "5",
        "NbPortes": "5",
        "Kilometrage": "174368",
        "KmGaranti": "Non garanti",
        "Couleur": "NOIR",
        "BoiteLibelle": "Automatique",
        "NbRapports": "5",
        "PrixVenteTTC": "6490",
        "PremiereMain": "FAUX",
        "GarantieLibelle": "3 MOIS OU 5000 KM",
        "CategorieLibelle": "Berline",
        "EquipementsSerieEtOption": "ABS|Airbags latéraux arrière|Airbags latéraux avant|Airbags rideaux|Allumage des phares automatique|Antipatinage|Boite automatique|Capteur de Pluie|Chargeur CD|Clim automatique|Détecteur de sous-gonflage|Direction assistée|ESP|GPS Cartographique|Jantes Alu|Lampes Xenon|Ordinateur de bord|Peinture métal|Phares antibrouillard|Radar de recul AR|Radar de stationnement AV|Radio CD MP3|Régulateur-Limiteur de vitesse|Rétros élec. dégivrants et rabattables|Sellerie cuir|Verrouillage centralisé des portes|Vitres électriques avant",
        "Photos": "11844615_01_hd.jpg|11844615_02_hd.jpg|11844615_03_hd.jpg|11844615_04_hd.jpg|11844615_05_hd.jpg|11844615_06_hd.jpg|11844615_07_hd.jpg|11844615_08_hd.jpg|11844615_09_hd.jpg|11844615_10_hd.jpg|11844615_11_hd.jpg",
        "Co2": "223",
        "Poids": "0",
        "PTAC": "0",
        "PTRA": "0",
        "ChargeUtile": "0",
        "Longueur": "4902",
        "Largeur": "1835",
        "Empattement": "0",
        "Hauteur": "1442",
        "Volume": "0"
      },
      {
        "CodePvo": "...",
        "SocieteNom": "...",
        "SocieteAdresse": "...",
        "SocieteCodePostal": "...",
        "SocieteVille": "...",
        "ContactsNoms": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones2": "...",
        "ContactsEmails": "...",
        "IdentifiantVehicule": "12254615",
        "ReferenceVehicule": "1225",
        "NumeroPolice": "0",
        "StatutStock": "ST",
        "Annee": "2006",
        "Date1Mec": "27-12-2006",
        "GenreLibelle": "Voitures",
        "Marque": "PEUGEOT",
        "Famille": "407",
        "Version": "1.6 HDI110 CONFORT PACK FAP",
        "Modele": "407 1.6 HDI110 CONFORT PACK FAP",
        "EnergieLibelle": "Diesel",
        "PuissanceFiscale": "6",
        "PuissanceReelle": "110",
        "Cylindree": "1560",
        "NbPlaces": "5",
        "NbPortes": "4",
        "Kilometrage": "125000",
        "KmGaranti": "Non garanti",
        "Couleur": "NOIR",
        "BoiteLibelle": "Manuelle",
        "NbRapports": "5",
        "PrixVenteTTC": "5990",
        "PremiereMain": "FAUX",
        "GarantieLibelle": "3 MOIS OU 5000 KM",
        "CategorieLibelle": "Berline",
        "EquipementsSerieEtOption": "Kit mains-libres Bluetooth|Peinture métal|Régulateur-Limiteur de vitesse|Radio CD|ABS|Airbag de colonne de direction|Airbags frontaux|Airbags latéraux avant|Airbags rideaux|Antipatinage|Clim automatique|Direction assistée|ESP|Ordinateur de bord|Phares antibrouillard|Radio CD MP3|Verrouillage auto. des portes en roulant|Verrouillage centralisé des portes|Vitres électriques avant|Pack electrique|Radio CD",
        "Photos": "12254615_01_hd.jpg|12254615_02_hd.jpg|12254615_03_hd.jpg|12254615_04_hd.jpg|12254615_05_hd.jpg|12254615_06_hd.jpg|12254615_07_hd.jpg|12254615_08_hd.jpg",
        "Co2": "140",
        "Poids": "0",
        "PTAC": "0",
        "PTRA": "0",
        "ChargeUtile": "0",
        "Longueur": "4676",
        "Largeur": "1811",
        "Empattement": "0",
        "Hauteur": "1447",
        "Volume": "0"
      },
      {
        "CodePvo": "...",
        "SocieteNom": "...",
        "SocieteAdresse": "...",
        "SocieteCodePostal": "...",
        "SocieteVille": "...",
        "ContactsNoms": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones2": "...",
        "ContactsEmails": "...",
        "IdentifiantVehicule": "12394615",
        "ReferenceVehicule": "1239",
        "NumeroPolice": "1372",
        "StatutStock": "ST",
        "Annee": "2006",
        "Date1Mec": "04-04-2006",
        "GenreLibelle": "Voitures",
        "Marque": "PEUGEOT",
        "Famille": "607",
        "Version": "2.7 V6 HDI GRIFFE FAP BAA",
        "Modele": "607 2.7 V6 HDI GRIFFE FAP BAA",
        "EnergieLibelle": "Diesel",
        "PuissanceFiscale": "13",
        "PuissanceReelle": "204",
        "Cylindree": "2721",
        "NbPlaces": "5",
        "NbPortes": "4",
        "Kilometrage": "145500",
        "KmGaranti": "Non garanti",
        "Couleur": "GRIS",
        "BoiteLibelle": "Manuelle séquent.",
        "NbRapports": "6",
        "PrixVenteTTC": "7490",
        "PremiereMain": "VRAI",
        "GarantieLibelle": "3 MOIS OU 5000 KM",
        "CategorieLibelle": "Berline",
        "EquipementsSerieEtOption": "ABS|Airbags latéraux arrière|Airbags latéraux avant|Airbags rideaux|Allumage des phares automatique|Antipatinage|Capteur de Pluie|Chargeur CD|Clim automatique bi-zones|Détecteur de sous-gonflage|Direction assistée|ESP|GPS TV + Chargeur CD|Jantes Alu|Lampes Xenon|Ordinateur de bord|Peinture métal|Phares antibrouillard|Radar de recul AR|Radar de stationnement AV|Radio CD MP3|Régulateur-Limiteur de vitesse|Rétros élec. dégivrants et rabattables|Rétroviseur intérieur électrochrome|Sellerie cuir|Sièges avant chauffants|Sièges avant électriques|Verrouillage auto. des portes en roulant|Verrouillage centralisé des portes|Vitres arrière électriques|Vitres électriques avant|Volant réglable en profondeur et hauteur",
        "Photos": "12394615_01_hd.jpg|12394615_02_hd.jpg|12394615_03_hd.jpg|12394615_04_hd.jpg|12394615_05_hd.jpg|12394615_06_hd.jpg|12394615_07_hd.jpg|12394615_08_hd.jpg|12394615_09_hd.jpg|12394615_10_hd.jpg|12394615_11_hd.jpg",
        "Co2": "223",
        "Poids": "0",
        "PTAC": "0",
        "PTRA": "0",
        "ChargeUtile": "0",
        "Longueur": "4902",
        "Largeur": "1835",
        "Empattement": "0",
        "Hauteur": "1442",
        "Volume": "0"
      },
      {
        "CodePvo": "...",
        "SocieteNom": "...",
        "SocieteAdresse": "...",
        "SocieteCodePostal": "...",
        "SocieteVille": "...",
        "ContactsNoms": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones2": "...",
        "ContactsEmails": "...",
        "IdentifiantVehicule": "12644615",
        "ReferenceVehicule": "1264",
        "NumeroPolice": "1392",
        "StatutStock": "ST",
        "Annee": "2007",
        "Date1Mec": "12-10-2007",
        "GenreLibelle": "Voitures",
        "Marque": "MERCEDES",
        "Famille": "CLASSE B",
        "Version": "180 CDI PACK DESIGN",
        "Modele": "CLASSE B 180 CDI PACK DESIGN",
        "EnergieLibelle": "Diesel",
        "PuissanceFiscale": "6",
        "PuissanceReelle": "109",
        "Cylindree": "1991",
        "NbPlaces": "5",
        "NbPortes": "5",
        "Kilometrage": "158900",
        "KmGaranti": "Non garanti",
        "Couleur": "GRIS",
        "BoiteLibelle": "Manuelle",
        "NbRapports": "6",
        "PrixVenteTTC": "7490",
        "PremiereMain": "FAUX",
        "GarantieLibelle": "3 MOIS OU 5000 KM",
        "CategorieLibelle": "Monospace",
        "EquipementsSerieEtOption": "ABS|Airbags frontaux|Airbags latéraux avant|Allumage des phares automatique|Antipatinage|Capteur de Pluie|Clim manuelle|Direction assistée|ESP|Jantes Alu|Ordinateur de bord|Phares antibrouillard|Rétroviseurs électriques dégivrants|Verrouillage auto. des portes en roulant|Verrouillage centralisé des portes|Vitres electriques avant",
        "Photos": "12644615_01_hd.jpg|12644615_02_hd.jpg|12644615_03_hd.jpg|12644615_04_hd.jpg|12644615_05_hd.jpg|12644615_06_hd.jpg|12644615_07_hd.jpg|12644615_08_hd.jpg",
        "Co2": "146",
        "Poids": "0",
        "PTAC": "0",
        "PTRA": "0",
        "ChargeUtile": "0",
        "Longueur": "4270",
        "Largeur": "1777",
        "Empattement": "0",
        "Hauteur": "1604",
        "Volume": "0"
      },
      {
        "CodePvo": "...",
        "SocieteNom": "...",
        "SocieteAdresse": "...",
        "SocieteCodePostal": "...",
        "SocieteVille": "...",
        "ContactsNoms": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones2": "...",
        "ContactsEmails": "...",
        "IdentifiantVehicule": "12694615",
        "ReferenceVehicule": "1269",
        "NumeroPolice": "1396",
        "StatutStock": "ST",
        "Annee": "2008",
        "Date1Mec": "30-01-2008",
        "GenreLibelle": "Voitures",
        "Marque": "PEUGEOT",
        "Famille": "407",
        "Version": "2.0 HDI136 PREMIUM BAA6 FAP",
        "Modele": "407 2.0 HDI136 PREMIUM BAA6 FAP",
        "EnergieLibelle": "Diesel",
        "PuissanceFiscale": "9",
        "PuissanceReelle": "136",
        "Cylindree": "1997",
        "NbPlaces": "5",
        "NbPortes": "4",
        "Kilometrage": "80788",
        "KmGaranti": "Non garanti",
        "Couleur": "GRIS",
        "BoiteLibelle": "Manuelle séquent.",
        "NbRapports": "6",
        "PrixVenteTTC": "7490",
        "PremiereMain": "FAUX",
        "GarantieLibelle": "3 MOIS OU 5000 KM",
        "CategorieLibelle": "Berline",
        "EquipementsSerieEtOption": "Radar de recul AR|ABS|Airbag de colonne de direction|Airbags frontaux|Airbags latéraux avant|Airbags rideaux|Antipatinage|Clim automatique bi-zones|Direction assistée|ESP|Jantes Alu|Ordinateur de bord|Pack Visibilité|Phares antibrouillard|Radio CD MP3|Régulateur-Limiteur de vitesse|Verrouillage auto. des portes en roulant|Verrouillage centralisé des portes|Vitres arrière électriques|Vitres électriques avant",
        "Photos": "12694615_01_hd.jpg|12694615_02_hd.jpg|12694615_03_hd.jpg|12694615_04_hd.jpg|12694615_05_hd.jpg|12694615_06_hd.jpg|12694615_07_hd.jpg|12694615_08_hd.jpg|12694615_09_hd.jpg|12694615_10_hd.jpg",
        "Co2": "189",
        "Poids": "0",
        "PTAC": "0",
        "PTRA": "0",
        "ChargeUtile": "0",
        "Longueur": "4676",
        "Largeur": "1811",
        "Empattement": "0",
        "Hauteur": "1455",
        "Volume": "0"
      },
      {
        "CodePvo": "...",
        "SocieteNom": "...",
        "SocieteAdresse": "...",
        "SocieteCodePostal": "...",
        "SocieteVille": "...",
        "ContactsNoms": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones2": "...",
        "ContactsEmails": "...",
        "IdentifiantVehicule": "12844615",
        "ReferenceVehicule": "1284",
        "NumeroPolice": "1411",
        "StatutStock": "ST",
        "Annee": "1999",
        "Date1Mec": "24-07-1998",
        "GenreLibelle": "Voitures",
        "Marque": "RENAULT",
        "Famille": "SCENIC",
        "Version": "1.9 D64 RTE",
        "Modele": "SCENIC 1.9 D64 RTE",
        "EnergieLibelle": "Diesel",
        "PuissanceFiscale": "5",
        "PuissanceReelle": "64",
        "Cylindree": "1870",
        "NbPlaces": "5",
        "NbPortes": "5",
        "Kilometrage": "335965",
        "KmGaranti": "Non garanti",
        "Couleur": "VERT",
        "BoiteLibelle": "Manuelle",
        "NbRapports": "5",
        "PrixVenteTTC": "1500",
        "PremiereMain": "FAUX",
        "GarantieLibelle": "3 MOIS OU 5000 KM",
        "CategorieLibelle": "Monospace",
        "EquipementsSerieEtOption": "Jantes Alu|ABS|Airbag conducteur|Airbags frontaux|Direction assistée|Radio cassette",
        "Photos": "12844615_01_hd.jpg|12844615_02_hd.jpg|12844615_03_hd.jpg|12844615_04_hd.jpg|12844615_05_hd.jpg|12844615_06_hd.jpg",
        "Co2": "0",
        "Poids": "0",
        "PTAC": "0",
        "PTRA": "0",
        "ChargeUtile": "0",
        "Longueur": "0",
        "Largeur": "0",
        "Empattement": "0",
        "Hauteur": "0",
        "Volume": "0"
      },
      {
        "CodePvo": "...",
        "SocieteNom": "...",
        "SocieteAdresse": "...",
        "SocieteCodePostal": "...",
        "SocieteVille": "...",
        "ContactsNoms": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones": "...",
        "ContactsTelephones2": "...",
        "ContactsEmails": "...",
        "IdentifiantVehicule": "12874615",
        "ReferenceVehicule": "1287",
        "NumeroPolice": "1414",
        "StatutStock": "ST",
        "Annee": "2008",
        "Date1Mec": "04-04-2008",
        "GenreLibelle": "Voitures",
        "Marque": "PEUGEOT",
        "Famille": "407",
        "Version": "2.0 HDI136 EXECUTIVE FAP",
        "Modele": "407 2.0 HDI136 EXECUTIVE FAP",
        "EnergieLibelle": "Diesel",
        "PuissanceFiscale": "8",
        "PuissanceReelle": "136",
        "Cylindree": "1997",
        "NbPlaces": "5",
        "NbPortes": "4",
        "Kilometrage": "104369",
        "KmGaranti": "Non garanti",
        "Couleur": "GRIS FER",
        "BoiteLibelle": "Manuelle",
        "NbRapports": "6",
        "PrixVenteTTC": "6490",
        "PremiereMain": "VRAI",
        "GarantieLibelle": "3 MOIS OU 5000 KM",
        "CategorieLibelle": "Berline",
        "EquipementsSerieEtOption": "ABS|Airbag de colonne de direction|Airbags frontaux|Airbags latéraux avant|Airbags rideaux|Antipatinage|Clim automatique bi-zones|Détecteur de sous-gonflage|Direction assistée|ESP|Ordinateur de bord|Pack Visibilité|Phares antibrouillard|Radio CD MP3|Régulateur-Limiteur de vitesse|Verrouillage auto. des portes en roulant|Verrouillage centralisé des portes|Vitres électriques avant",
        "Photos": "12874615_01_hd.jpg|12874615_02_hd.jpg|12874615_03_hd.jpg|12874615_04_hd.jpg|12874615_05_hd.jpg|12874615_06_hd.jpg|12874615_07_hd.jpg",
        "Co2": "155",
        "Poids": "0",
        "PTAC": "0",
        "PTRA": "0",
        "ChargeUtile": "0",
        "Longueur": "4676",
        "Largeur": "1811",
        "Empattement": "0",
        "Hauteur": "1447",
        "Volume": "0"
      },
        ....
```

it's possible to modify some attributs ? 
i want to rename `Marque` to `brand` and `Famille`to `model`

i want to use a script bash (Ubuntu server) to do this modification.

Comment: Would a Python solution be acceptable? it would be *so* much simpler and safer.  You can inline the Python code into your shell script using heredoc syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `jq`:

```
jq -M '.Stock.Vehicule[] = (.Stock.Vehicule[] | with_entries(.key |= (if . == "Marque" then "brand" else . end)) | with_entries(.key |= (if . == "Famille" then "model" else . end)))' filename.json
```

The important parts of the filter are the

```
with_entries(.key |= (if . == "Marque"  then "brand" else . end))
with_entries(.key |= (if . == "Famille" then "model" else . end))
```

clauses that modify the keys of the objects they're applied to in the manner you wanted. The rest is

```
jq '.Stock.Vehicule[] = (.Stock.Vehicule[] | that filter)' filename.json
```

...which assigns to `.Stock.Vehicule[]` the filter-modified version of itself.

**Addendum:** I suppose you might, in this case, get away with sed:

```
sed 's/"Marque":/"brand":/;s/"Famille":/"model":/' filename.json
```

but **JSON is not a format you want to edit with sed,** or any other tool that treats its input as flat text. Benign whitespaces (and particular newlines) that don't invalidate the JSON will confuse such scripts. It is generally better to parse JSON with tools that understand JSON (like `jq`).